# Django - Custom model cannot appear on User model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have created a model in Django v4, and I want to show the information inside the User admin view. After migrating, a new table was created successfully and data is being stored. Here is the code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    address = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Extra Information'

@admin.register(ProfileInline)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ProfileInline,
    ]
```

The table that has been created has the following stored:

| id | address | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Test | 2 |

Where the **user_id** column, is a foreign key from the **auth_user** table, which is created automatically (I guess?).

Now, when I try to run, makemigrations, etc, it shows me the following:

`AttributeError: type object 'ProfileInline' has no attribute '_meta'`

What is the proper way to have the information appended to the User, as the default sections do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. The admin.py should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Extra Information'

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ProfileInline,
    ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach in this case would be to inherit Django's AbstractUser class, add your additional fields then set Django's `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings so that django uses your model for authentication.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    address = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

`settings.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "<your_app_name>.Profile"
```

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, but I didn't want to replace the default User model, because the address field is not required. But thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can do that by overriding the address field and setting it as None
`address = None`.
Disclaimer : I have not used this method in a project, but should work for trivial fields like address.